# Variable appending vs multiple echo - Memory wise

Tags: php, memory-management

I was wondering, is there an impact on the memory usage and the speed of the application in these 3 scenarios:

For the sake of example, I'll create a table

```
<table>
<?
foreach($tableDataFromMysql as $rows){
echo "<tr>";
echo "<td>";
echo $cell1;
echo "</td>";
echo "<td>";
echo $cell2;
echo "</td>";
echo "<td>";
echo $cell3;
echo "</td>";
echo "</tr>";
}
?>
</table>
```

Or

```
<table>
<?
foreach($tableDataFromMysql as $rows){
echo "<tr><td>".$cell1."</td>"."<td>".$cell2."</td>"."<td>".$cell3."</td></tr>";
}
?>
</table>
```

Or

```
<table>
<?
foreach($tableDataFromMysql as $rows){
$output="<tr>";
$output.= "<td>";
$output.= $cell1;
$output.= "</td>";
$output.= "<td>";
$output.= $cell2;
$output.="</td>";
$output.= "<td>";
$output.= $cell3;
$output.= "</td>";
$output.= "</tr>";
echo $output;
}
?>
</table>
```

There mught be *n* number of variables in the row to output. For this example i've just used static count number of variables to be output.

So, the question : **Does it make a difference in memory usage?**

Comment: Unless you're dragging around incredibly huge strings, I suspect the overhead of multiple echo calls (to copy the data from PHP -> Apache) will outweight the concatenation/allocation overhead. But... you'll have to benchmark it, because for only a few 10s of lines of code, the actual absolute difference in cpu time is going to be measured in microseconds.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes there is a difference. Since variable assignment is storage, it requires memory. Printing data will send it to the output buffer which is usually pre-allocated.

Per example, consider these this script:

```
echo 'foo';
echo memory_get_usage();  // 632600
echo 'foo';
echo memory_get_usage();  // 632600 (0 bytes have been allocated)
```

Compared to this one:

```
echo 'foo';
echo memory_get_usage();  // 633088
$a = 'foo';
echo memory_get_usage();  // 633352 (264 bytes have been allocated)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can simply try it out using [use memory_get_usage()](http://php.net/memory_get_usage) / [memory_get_peak_usage()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.memory-get-peak-usage.php). However, I would recommend not taking care for such micro-optimisation in the first place. Better use a template engine, which is obviously slower, but gathers you more maintainable code by dividing logic and view.

Answer (score 0):

Between the first two examples I believe any differences would be miniscule.

For the third example, only if the resultset is absolutely massive will you see any noticeable performance degradation.  But it will be the most memory intensive.

It would be simple for you to test:

1. create a dummy resultset that is ~10000 rows
2. store the `microtime(true)` immediately before the looping begins
3. get the `microtime(true)` immediately after the looping ends
4. print out the difference in the two microtimes to see execution time in seconds
5. print out `memory_get_peak_usage()` at the end of the script
6. swap out the three different pieces of code
7. run each piece of code multiple times to account forvariables in the environment

compare results from the three different methods

Answer (score 0):

That's another question out of nowhere.
I bet you have not a single problem with memory usage (at least one, relevant to this question), but asking with no reason, just in case.
That's bad way to ask questions.

Memory usage is not the only reason to prefer one method over another.
**Especially** if it's negligible amount of memory to be used.
Especially if there are some optimization techniques to use.

Everything you posted is just matter of coding style, not memory usage.

For sake of readability and good application design, neither of above should be used but most programmers agree that it should be **a template** based on escaping from HTML and alternative syntax for control structures principles:

```
<table>
<? foreach($tableDataFromMysql as $row): ?>
 <tr>
  <td><?=$row['cell1']?></td>
  <td><?=$row['cell2']?></td>
  <td><?=$row['cell3']?></td>
 </tr>
<? endforeach ?>
</table>
```

Note HTML formatting and **highlighting** - real things to care about.

Comment: Yup! Just asking why's and if's. And thanks for the escaping advice!